# How to change user avatar using REST API?

Tags: rest-api, avatar

I've tried all the methods, but nothing works.
When creating a new user with the avatars URLs already specified for the pictures, nothing happens either.

Comment: You will get more help and suggestions if you share the methods you tried and post errors or shortcomings.

Comment: @q-studio I tried https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/users/#create-a-user
and 
https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/users/#update-a-user

Comment: WordPress does not natively support avatars, apart from Gravatars, which are entirely based on the user's email address. If you're using a plugin to support some other kind of avatar, then how to set that by the REST API would depend on the plugin, and you should direct your question to its author.